# How to make different users profile pages for different user types in Open Atrium2?

Tags: distributions

I have 3 different user types and I want to provide a specific profile edit page for each. The user type is set when registering for an account. I have the profile fields associated to each user type created in config/people/accounts, but I'm lost on how to create the separate pages for each user type and then to trigger the loading of the correct page based on the users type.

Answer (score 0):

I have not find a such module in the OpenAtrium bundle. You can use the contribute module https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2
Profile2 allows for creating multiple profile types, which may be assigned to roles via permissions (e.g. a general profile + a customer profile)

Comment: I'm only just beginning to grasp Page Manager and Panes and am thinking it could be done with PM and P with more display flexibility that with Profile2. But I'm unable to see where the profiles page is defined and so how to override it.

Comment: Panels it is the cool tool. But it has another reason. It charges of the layout system. The Profile2 module helps you to attach different types of node to users with with different roles. So **Panels** - layout, **Profile2** - data .